# How can theano.scan execute external code

Tags: python, theano

We know that theano scan compile and execute the code with it's code in the symbolic graph. How to execute external (or irrelevant) code, for example:

```
i=0
def x():
    global i
    i=i+1

def power_of_2(previous_power, max_value):
    x()
    return [previous_power*2,i], theano.scan_module.until(previous_power*2 > max_value)

max_value = T.scalar()
[values, v],_ = theano.scan(power_of_2,
                        outputs_info = [T.constant(1.),None],
                        non_sequences = max_value,
                        n_steps = 1024)

f = theano.function([max_value], [values,v])

print (f(45))
```

The problem is, x() will not be executed. How to solve it?

Comment: In your example `x()` has no effect on the Theano computation (it doesn't change any shared variables and its result is not used in computing any of the outputs from the scan step function); is this representative of what you want to do?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw I wanted to output i, but the i will not be changed with the scan.